# Prove $\vert\lambda_{1,2}\vert\leq 1$.

Tags: inequality

I want to prove $$\vert\lambda_{1,2}\vert = \left\vert\dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}\cos(kh)\pm \dfrac{1}{1+2\mu}\sqrt{1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)}\right\vert\leq 1,$$ for $\mu,k,h>0.$ There are two cases. First case is $1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)\geq 0$ and second case is $1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)<0$. For first case, I prove like this. Please check my answer.

\begin{eqnarray}
\vert\lambda_{1,2}\vert &=& \left\vert\dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}\cos(kh)\pm \dfrac{1}{1+2\mu}\sqrt{1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)}\right\vert \newline
&\leq& \left\vert\dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}\cos(kh)\right\vert+ \left\vert\dfrac{1}{1+2\mu}\sqrt{1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)}\right\vert \text{(triangle inequality)} \newline
&=& \left\vert\dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}\right\vert\left\vert\cos(kh)\right\vert+ \left\vert\dfrac{1}{1+2\mu}\right\vert\left\vert\sqrt{1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)}\right\vert \text{(properties of abs value)} \newline
&=& \dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}\left\vert\cos(kh)\right\vert+ \dfrac{1}{1+2\mu}\left\vert\sqrt{1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)}\right\vert \text{(since $\mu>0$)} \newline
&\leq& \dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}+ \dfrac{1}{1+2\mu} \text{(since $\left\vert\cos(kh)\right\vert$ and $\left\vert\sqrt{1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)}\right\vert$ maximum in 1)} \newline
&=& \dfrac{2\mu + 1}{1+2\mu}\newline
&=& 1
\end{eqnarray}
So, I conclude that $\vert\lambda_{1,2}\vert\leq 1$. Is it right answer? If there are some mistake, please correct my answer.

Second case, $1-4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)<0$. I confused for second case, because if second case applied, then square root is complex number and I can't conclude $\vert\lambda_{1,2}\vert\leq 1$. Anyone can explain me how to prove $\vert\lambda_{1,2}\vert\leq 1$ in second case?

Comment: Your triangle inequality is not right: We have that $|a+b|\leqslant |a|+|b|$, so $|a-b|=|a+(-b)|\leqslant|a|+|-b|=|a|+|b|$.

Comment: I have edited my triangle inequality above. Please check again my answer.

Comment: I think it's ok now. But I'm not sure if it's true when $1<4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)$.

Comment: I don't think you need to consider the second case.

Comment: Because of $\mu^2>0$ and $0\leq \sin^2(kh)\leq 1$, it is possible to satisfying the second case, $1-4\mu^2\sin^2(kh)<0$. Because the square root is complex number, we still not need to consider the second case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a second case, we have:

$$|\lambda_{1,2}|= \left\vert\dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}\cos(kh)\pm\left(\dfrac{1}{1+2\mu}\sqrt{4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)-1}\right)i\right\vert= \sqrt{\left\vert\dfrac{2\mu}{1+2\mu}\cos(kh)\right\vert^2+ \left\vert\dfrac{1}{1+2\mu}\sqrt{4\mu^2 \sin^2(kh)-1}\right\vert^2}=\sqrt{\frac{4\mu^2\cos^2(kh)+4\mu^2\sin^2(kh)-1}{(1+2\mu)^2}}=\sqrt{\frac{2\mu-1}{2\mu+1}}$$

Which is less than 1 because $\mu\geq \frac{1}{2}$ (if $\mu < \frac{1}{2}$: $4\mu^2\sin^2(kh)<1$)